# How can I retrieve POST data in Firefox without use of an addon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, greasemonkey

This is a bit of an emergency.  I've written a very large article without saving my progress (I know, not the brightest), and when I submitted it, I ended up being redirected to an error.  If I hit the "Back" button, then I'm taking to a blank page.  If I hit the "Refresh" button on the error page, it tries to resubmit the POST data containing my message (so I know it still exists).

The problem is, I don't own any firefox plugins for viewing the POST data, but I know it's there on the page still, and if I had a method, I would be able to view and retrieve my POST data by refreshing.

I'm using Firefox 10.0.4 on Gentoo.  I do have the greasemonkey plugin installed, but I wasn't able to locate/write a greasemonkey script to do this for me.  I was also unable to find a javascript solution, and every plugin I frantically installed to firefox requires a restart (which will result in losing my POST data forever).

Is there ANY way I could retrieve my POST data in firefox with only the tools I have right now?  Are there any external tools for viewing the post data in memory or as firefox environment variables?

Edit: Would it be possible to grep the entirety of my RAM and swap, looking for my POST data?  How practical would that be?  Sorry for all the questions, I may be in panic mode right now.

Comment: A sniffer like Wireshark would let you capture everything that gets sent from the browser on whatever network interface its using ...

Comment: Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp), re-issue the request and you'll have your POST data. Brotip: type large articles in an offline text editor like Notepad++ before submitting them. I've ran into session timeouts myself a few times, growing this habit as a result.

Comment: To prevent this issue in the future, use an extension like [Lazarus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/lazarus-form-recovery/) to allow auto-saving of data you type into forms.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] I don't own any firefox plugins for viewing the POST data [...]

Firebug: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/

> [...] every plugin I frantically installed to firefox requires a
>   restart [...]

Firebug does not require that you restart you browser.

[image: fb]